# Derive Auto-Generated Entity Class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a `edmx` file being set its `Code Generation Strategy` to `None` and a T4 template set to it, where I removed the *Factory Method Creation* logic. I have introduced some additional method for few of the entities on a separate file through partial class.

Ex: I have introduced few methods for the entity `User` on partial class and I derived the classes `Admin` and `Person` from `User` where I want to introduce some other methods.

The issue I'm facing here is, while assigning a value to the navigation property of `Admin`, it throws the exception `Object mapping could not be found for Type with identity 'CivilRegistry.ControlledModel.Admin'.`

User Class:

```
public partial class User
{

    protected static UserRepository repository = new UserRepository();

    public User Insert(User user)
    {
        user.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
        user.AddedUserId = this.UserId;
        return repository.Insert(user);
    }
    //
    //Other methods goes here.
    //
}
```

Admin Class:

```
public class Admin : User
{
    public Admin() { }

    private Admin(User user)
    {
        this.UserName = user.UserName;
        //
        //Other properties
        //
        this.AddedUser = user.AddedUser; //This line throws, Exception.
    }

    public static Admin FindBy(int id)
    {
        //repository.FindByID returns an instance of User entity.
        return new Admin(repository.FindByID(user => user.UserId == id && user.RoleId == (int)RoleEnum.Admin));
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: have you considered going code-only/POCO? And please say a bit more about your T4 template you used - without seeing this, the question is very hard to answer.

Comment: I just commented out the line `WriteFactoryMethod(entity, code);` everywhere on T4, other than this everything is same as auto-generated.

Comment: @CarstenKönig: I've updated my question. Please let me know, if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported. You cannot define entity in EDMX and then derive additional classes from the entity in your code. Derived classes created this way are not entities any more and cannot be retrieved or persisted by EF because EF doesn't know how to map them anymore.

The reason why it fails in assigning navigation property is that EF knows that `Admin` is `User` and it tries to attach it to the context but it doesn't find the `Admin` type in mapping (EDMX).

The solution is mapping the inheritance = moving your inheritance to EDMX where you will define `User` entity and derived `Person` and `Admin` entities. [Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/24/table-per-hierarchy-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx) you have some tutorial.